# How to use RQL to query rollbar to group by time period?

Tags: rollbar

How do I construct an RQL statement that will count errors by, say, day. This gets the number of errors over a seven day period, but how do I count per day?

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM item_occurrence
WHERE timestamp > unix_timestamp() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the operator you are looking for is the `timestamp div X` operator. You can use it to bucket the query results if you use it in a `group by` statement. Try this:

```
SELECT count(*), timestamp div (60 * 60 * 24)
FROM item_occurrence
WHERE timestamp > unix_timestamp() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 2 asc
```

The second column will be formatted as an integer, not sure if there's a way to fix it, but that should allow you to see the results grouped into a chosen timeslice.

Comment: This seems closer to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Does this get you what you are after?

```
SELECT item.hash, count(item.id)
FROM item_occurrence
WHERE timestamp > unix_timestamp() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 6
GROUP BY item.id 
ORDER BY item.id desc
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing here? This seems to produce 34 rows. I want, say, number of errors grouped by day for a 7 day period...

Comment: @Aaron -- That was the closest I could come  RQL doesn't have a `DATE` function, so I can't group them by date.

Comment: Right, that's also what rollbar said.